# Creating an object with FY as 'key' and Quarter as 'value' - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, javascript-objects

I'm trying to create an object whose 'key' will be the fiscal year (FY) and 'values' are the quarter dates.

```
//Format
{
   FY:{
        [Quarter dates]
   },
}
```

The quarter dates count varies from 1 to 4. If only one-quarter info is given, take the previous FY as a reference and increase by 1 to know the present FY.

Based on the Period end dates I'm able to group the quarters but calculating the fiscal year is what I need help with. The FY will follow these rules.

1. The most repeated quarter years will be the fiscal year.
2. If quarters have two different years with a count of 2 each then we can pick the smallest year as FY.
   Eg: Periods =[06/21], Quarters =[09/20,12/20,03/21,06/21] then FY =2020

A company can change its period end date so you can expect a gap in quarter dates. In the following example, the company used Dec as a period-end till 2019 after that they are using Mar as the period-end. A gap of one quarter (Jan, Feb, Mar months) has been omitted.

```
const quarters = [
    "12 / 30 / 2021",
    "09 / 30 / 2021",
    "06 / 30 / 2021",
    "03 / 30 / 2021",
    "12 / 30 / 2020",
    "09 / 30 / 2020",
    "06 / 30 / 2020",
    "12 / 30 / 2019",
    "09 / 30 / 2019",
    "06 / 30 / 2019",
    "03 / 30 / 2019",
    "12 / 30 / 2018",
    "09 / 30 / 2018",
    "06 / 30 / 2018",
    "03 / 30 / 2018",
];
const periods = [
    "03 / 30 / 2021",
    "12 / 30 / 2019",
    "12 / 30 / 2018",
    "12/30/2017"
];

const groupQuarters = [];
let group = [];
while (periods.length > 0) {
    let p = new Date(periods[0].toString());
    group = [];
    while (quarters.length > 0) {
        let q = new Date(quarters[0].toString());
        if (q > p) {
            group.push(quarters[0]);
            quarters.shift();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    const yearCal = (groups) => {
        // unable to figure this out.
        return 2020;
    }
    groupQuarters.push({ [yearCal(group)]: group });
    periods.shift();
}


console.log(groupQuarters);
```

```
Expected output:
[
  {
      2021: [
          '12 / 30 / 2021',
          '09 / 30 / 2021',
          '06 / 30 / 2021'
      ]
  },
  {
      2020: [
          '03 / 30 / 2021',
          '12 / 30 / 2020',
          '09 / 30 / 2020',
          '06 / 30 / 2020'
      ]
  },
  {
      2019: [
          '12 / 30 / 2019',
          '09 / 30 / 2019',
          '06 / 30 / 2019',
          '03 / 30 / 2019'
      ]
  },
  {
      2018: [
          '12 / 30 / 2018',
          '09 / 30 / 2018',
          '06 / 30 / 2018',
          '03 / 30 / 2018'
      ]
  }
]
```

```
Test Case - 2:
const quarters = [
  "12 / 30 / 2020",
  "09 / 30 / 2020",
  "06 / 30 / 2020",
  "03 / 30 / 2020",
  "12 / 30 / 2019",
  "09 / 30 / 2019",
  "06 / 30 / 2019",
  "03 / 30 / 2019",
  "12 / 30 / 2018"
];
const periods = [
  "09 / 30 / 2020",
  "09 / 30 / 2019",
  "09 / 30 / 2018",
];

Expected Output:
[
  {
    2021: [
      '12 / 30 / 2020',
    ]
  },
  {
    2020: [
      "09 / 30 / 2020",
      "06 / 30 / 2020",
      "03 / 30 / 2020",
      "12 / 30 / 2019",
    ]
  },
  {
    2019: [
      "09 / 30 / 2019",
      "06 / 30 / 2019",
      "03 / 30 / 2019",
      "12 / 30 / 2018",
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the expected output has little objects, each with one year property, and not one object having all of those (year) properties?

Comment: That's the expected output format. Based on that future q1, q2.... labels are generated. But please follow the output format.

Comment: Would it work if we would take the earliest (last) quarter of a group and take its year as fiscal year and add 1 to it if its quarter is in the second half of that year? (it works with the 2 test cases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there are no gaps *within* a period -- i.e. no gaps between two quarters that belong to the same period -- you could apply this logic:

- When the last quarter is known of the period (i.e. it equals the period-end), subtract 2 quarters and take that quarter's year as financial year
- When the last quarter is not known of the period -- this may happen at the start of the array, where the current period is not yet completed -- add one quarter to the first quarter of that period and take that quarter's year as financial year.

As it is nice to *map* the `periods` array one-to-one to get the result array, it might sometimes be needed to strip the last period entry (like in the test case 1), or insert an unfinished period at the start of that array (also in test case 1).

Not related, but I avoided Date objects for this task, and included functions to convert the input strings to numbers and back:

```js
function chunkByYear(quarters, periods) {
    // Converter functions between string and unique quarter number
    const toQuarter = s => s.match(/^\d+|\d+$/g).reduce((m, y) => m/3 - 1 + y*4);
    const toDate = q => ((q % 4 + 1)*3 + "/30/" + (q >> 2)).padStart(10, "0");

    const periodNums = periods.map(toQuarter);
    const quarterNums = quarters.map(toQuarter);
    // Make sure all quarters are after at least one period end
    while (quarterNums[quarterNums.length-1] <= periodNums[periodNums.length-1]) periodNums.push(periodNums[periodNums.length-1] - 4);
    // Remove periods that have no content:
    while (quarterNums[0] <= periodNums[0]) periodNums.shift();
    quarterNums.push(0); // To make sure `findIndex` always finds an index
    return periodNums.map((p, i, {length}) => {
        const period = quarterNums.splice(0, quarterNums.findIndex(q => q <= p));
        return { [(i ? period[0] - 2 : period[period.length-1] + 1) >> 2]: period.map(toDate) };
    });
}

{ // test 1
    const quarters = [
        "12 / 30 / 2021", "09 / 30 / 2021", "06 / 30 / 2021",
        "03 / 30 / 2021", "12 / 30 / 2020", "09 / 30 / 2020", "06 / 30 / 2020",
        "12 / 30 / 2019", "09 / 30 / 2019", "06 / 30 / 2019", "03 / 30 / 2019",
        "12 / 30 / 2018", "09 / 30 / 2018", "06 / 30 / 2018", "03 / 30 / 2018",
    ];
    const periods =  ["03 / 30 / 2021", "12 / 30 / 2019", "12 / 30 / 2018", "12 / 30 / 2017"];
    console.log(chunkByYear(quarters, periods));
}
{ // test 2
    const quarters = [
        "12 / 30 / 2020",
        "09 / 30 / 2020", "06 / 30 / 2020", "03 / 30 / 2020", "12 / 30 / 2019",
        "09 / 30 / 2019", "06 / 30 / 2019", "03 / 30 / 2019", "12 / 30 / 2018"
    ];
    const periods =  ["09 / 30 / 2020", "09 / 30 / 2019", "09 / 30 / 2018"];
    console.log(chunkByYear(quarters, periods));
}
{ // test 3
    const quarters = [
        "06 / 30 / 2021", "03 / 30 / 2021", "12 / 30 / 2020", "09 / 30 / 2020",
        "06 / 30 / 2020", "03 / 30 / 2020", "12 / 30 / 2019", "09 / 30 / 2019",
        "06 / 30 / 2019",
    ];
    const periods = ["06 / 30 / 2021", "06 / 30 / 2020", "06 / 30 / 2019"];
    console.log(chunkByYear(quarters, periods));
}
{ // test 4
    const quarters = [
        "06 / 30 / 2021", "03 / 30 / 2021", "12 / 30 / 2020", "09 / 30 / 2020",
        "06 / 31 / 2020", "03 / 30 / 2020", "12 / 30 / 2019", "09 / 30 / 2019",
        "06 / 30 / 2019", "03 / 30 / 2019", "12 / 30 / 2018", "09 / 30 / 2018",
    ];
    const periods = ["06 / 30 / 2021", "06 / 31 / 2020", "06 / 30 / 2019"];
    console.log(chunkByYear(quarters, periods));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try it :

```js
const quarters = [
    "12 / 30 / 2021",
    "09 / 30 / 2021",
    "06 / 30 / 2021",
    "03 / 30 / 2021",
    "12 / 30 / 2020",
    "09 / 30 / 2020",
    "06 / 30 / 2020",
    "12 / 30 / 2019",
    "09 / 30 / 2019",
    "06 / 30 / 2019",
    "03 / 30 / 2019",
    "12 / 30 / 2018",
    "09 / 30 / 2018",
    "06 / 30 / 2018",
    "03 / 30 / 2018",
]
const periods = [
    "03 / 30 / 2021",
    "12 / 30 / 2019",
    "12 / 30 / 2018",
    "12/30/2017"
]
const quarters1 = [
  "12 / 30 / 2020",
  "09 / 30 / 2020",
  "06 / 30 / 2020",
  "03 / 30 / 2020",
  "12 / 30 / 2019",
  "09 / 30 / 2019",
  "06 / 30 / 2019",
  "03 / 30 / 2019",
  "12 / 30 / 2018"
];
const periods1 = [
  "09 / 30 / 2020",
  "09 / 30 / 2019",
  "09 / 30 / 2018",
];
const getGroupQuarter = (qt, pr) => {
  let tmpCheck = qt
  return pr.reduce((result,period) => {
    let datePeriod = new Date(period)
    let key = getKeyQuarter(datePeriod)
    let qtrFill =  tmpCheck.filter(quarter => new Date(quarter) > datePeriod)
    tmpCheck =  tmpCheck.filter(quarter =>!(new Date(quarter) > datePeriod))
    return !qtrFill.length ? result :[...result, {[key] : qtrFill}]
  }, [])
}
const getKeyQuarter = (pr) => {
  let monthValidate = pr.getMonth()
  return monthValidate > 5 ? pr.getFullYear() + 1 : pr.getFullYear()
}
console.log(getGroupQuarter(quarters1, periods1));
console.log(getGroupQuarter(quarters, periods));
```

Comment: This logic works only for the given list. Consider the following cases. 1. If you omit the top two-quarter dates it will result in failure. 2. please find the test case-2  I've added in the question

Comment: i 've edit answer for new case of you. 
expect array  is wrong : `The most repeated years will be the fiscal year and if an FY has quarters with two different years with an exact count i.e.2, then we can pick the smallest value`

Comment: The second test case will fail here as it doesn't match the criteria, Please compare the outputs which I've posted vs your output. The FY 2020 should contain 09/30, 06/30, 3/30 of 2020, and 12/30 of 2019

Comment: in the question, you  write : `then we can pick the smallest value`

Comment: 2 expect result of you is asynchronous